# Invoke edit item ribbon from custom table checkbox

Tags: custom-list, ribbon, edit

I am using SPServices and datatables to make up some fast customized tables on a SharePoint 2010 page.

In one of the columns on the custom table I have a check box beside each row.

I would like to bring up the Standard SharePoint 2010 edit item ribbon when the box is checked with JavaScript but can't work out how to invoke it.

The items in the custom table are from a Standard SharePoint list, so I have the list and item ID if required.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I have experience in doing something similar (to invoke a ribbon command). I used Javascript profiler in IE to find out the function call for the event that I was trying to invoke and then added it into my custom function.

On a normal SP list view page, run the profiler before selecting a list item, stop the profiler and figure out the function calls it does to invoke the ribbon.

Comment: Hmm, I had a look through the profilr,  will take another go at it

Comment: Hi tachi, were you able to solve the problem?

Comment: Hi Houratious, I wasn't able to invoke the standard ribbon. I didn't particularly require all the functions on it so didn't spend much time on it. Would still be useful to know though.